# HttpGet unable to setHeader properly

Tags: java, curl, uber-api

I am working on Uber API's and trying to get user profile using instructions from [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-me)

following `curl` command works fine and can get user information from uber:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://api.uber.com/v1/me"
```

However, my Java code is not working - but **receiving 401 response** from server.

```
HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet("https://api.uber.com/v1/me");
httpGetRequest.setHeader("Authorization: Bearer", accessTokenModel.getAccess_token());
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpGetRequest);
response.getWriter().println("httpget response:" + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

Any idea why I am getting error on my GET request.
I also tried HttpGet addHeader method to add the header but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the header is "Authorization" and the value is "Bearer XXXX".  So

```
httpGetRequest.setHeader("Authorization: Bearer", accessTokenModel.getAccess_token());
```

should be

```
httpGetRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessTokenModel.getAccess_token());
```